# Using Java function annotations at call time to call external code

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Is there a way in Java to add an annotation to a method so that whenever it gets called, a method in another module gets called as well?

For example, let's say I've got a method called `reportSuccess(*parameters*)` defined in another module that I want to be called whenever a function annotated with `@ShouldReportSuccess(*parameters*)` gets called. In Python this is pretty simple , but I'm not sure how to do it in Java. I've found ways to iterate through annotated methods at runtime using reflection (like [here](https://keyholesoftware.com/2014/09/15/java-annotations-using-reflection/)), but not how I could then modify the annotated methods to call the external method.

Comment: You are looking for "Aspect Oriented Programming", or AOP.

Comment: aop is quite involved, using proxy class or dynamic code generation to call the methods mentioned in the annotations. It's by far not as simple as evaluating annotations via reflection.

Comment: You're thinking of a decorator. You're better off creating a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

While similar in syntax, a java annotation does not work like a python decorator.

In python, a decorator is syntactic sugar which calls a function with the current function as the parameter.

```
@my_decorator
def my_function:
    pass
```

Is the same thing as

```
def my_function: pass
my_function = my_decorator(my_function)
```

In java, annotations are strictly for metadata as far as the JVM is concerned. This metadata is actually saved in the class file and can be fetched independent of the classloader.

You can actually do some pretty creative things using a annotation processor or a library like lombok. But these things are done at compile-time, not run-time.